# Vertx Hazelcast Cluster Error "There is no discovery strategy factory to create ..." when using AWS Join Strategy

Tags: java, jvm, hazelcast, vert.x

I am trying to setup a simple vertx cluster in aws.(you can find all the code [here](https://github.com/lmnzr/vertx-hazelcast-cluster))

In the pom file I already add all the depedency I need, including vertx-hazelcast and hazelcast plugin for aws.

As for The Main Class it is quite simple and all the hazelcast setup is prepared in the main class.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getSimpleName());
        Config hazelcastConfig = new Config();


        hazelcastConfig.getNetworkConfig().getInterfaces().
                 setEnabled(true).addInterface("10.0.*.*");
        JoinConfig joinConfig = hazelcastConfig.getNetworkConfig().getJoin();
        joinConfig.getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
        joinConfig.getAwsConfig()
                .setEnabled(true)
                .setProperty("region", "ap-southeast-1")
                .setProperty("tag-key", "aws:cloudformation:stack-name")
                .setProperty("tag-value", "EC2ContainerService-test-cluster");
        hazelcastConfig.getNetworkConfig().setJoin(joinConfig);


        ClusterManager mgr = new HazelcastClusterManager(hazelcastConfig);
        String hostAddress = getAddress();

        VertxOptions options = new VertxOptions()
                .setClusterManager(mgr)
                .setHAEnabled(true);

        EventBusOptions ebOptions = new EventBusOptions()
                .setClustered(true)
                .setHost(hostAddress);

        options.setEventBusOptions(ebOptions);

        Vertx.clusteredVertx(options, handler->{
            if(handler.succeeded()){
                DeploymentOptions containerOption = new DeploymentOptions().setHa(false); 
                handler.result().deployVerticle(Verticle.class,containerOption,deployHandler->{
                    if(handler.succeeded()){
                        log.info("Verticle Deployed");
                    }else{
                        log.severe("Verticle Deployment Failed");
                    }
                });
            } else{
                log.severe(handler.cause().getMessage());
            }
        });

    }
}
```

I always run into this error whenever I run the fat jar.

```
Caused by: com.hazelcast.config.properties.ValidationException: There is no discovery strategy factory to create 'D
iscoveryStrategyConfig{properties={tag-value=EC2ContainerService-test-cluster, region=ap-southeast-1, tag-key=aws:c
loudformation:stack-name}, className='com.hazelcast.aws.AwsDiscoveryStrategy', discoveryStrategyFactory=null}' Is i
t a typo in a strategy classname? Perhaps you forgot to include implementation on a classpath?
```

Is there anything missing in my code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message usually means that you don't have [hazelcast-aws.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.hazelcast/hazelcast-aws) plugin in your classpath.

I see that you have it in your Maven dependencies, but please make sure that:

1. You use the compatible `hazelcast-aws` version with your `hazelcast` version (you can find the compatibility information [here](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-aws#hazelcast-discovery-plugin-for-aws)).
2. Your JAR really includes classes from the `com.hazelcast.aws` package.
3. Your JAR includes the file [resources/META-INF/services/com.hazelcast.spi.discovery.DiscoveryStrategyFactory](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-aws/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/com.hazelcast.spi.discovery.DiscoveryStrategyFactory).
4. Your `resources/META-INF/services/com.hazelcast.spi.discovery.DiscoveryStrategyFactory` does contain the entry [com.hazelcast.aws.AwsDiscoveryStrategyFactory](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-aws/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/com.hazelcast.spi.discovery.DiscoveryStrategyFactory#L17)

If anything of above is not correct, then you need to revisit how your fat JAR is built. One of the solutions of having it all in place is to have a dependency to `hazelcast-all` (not `hazelcast`). This will release you from all these issues.

Comment: hi, thanks for yoor comment. I have already make sure that the version match, the dependecy is also there,  the file resources/META-INF/services/com.hazelcast.spi.discovery.DiscoveryStrategyFactory is also there. However, I still get the error.

Comment: What is the content of your `resources/META-INF/services/com.hazelcast.spi.discovery.DiscoveryStrategyFactory` file? Is AWS listed there?

Comment: it only contain com.hazelcast.spi.discovery.multicast.MulticastDiscoveryStrategyFactory

Comment: Ok, so that is the reason why it does not work. Let me reply in the answer on the solutions, because the formatting is better.

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your solution  it is working now.

Comment: For me the problem that the Maven shade plugin clobbers the services file. The solution was to configure the `ServicesResourceTransformer` to merges the services files - https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html#ServicesResourceTransformer